# Deserialize potentially empty string using Serde

Tags: rust, serde

I've read [the docs](https://serde.rs), but I haven't seen a way to solve my problem. I'm parsing an API response which on success would return only a 2xx status code, while on bad requests it sends JSON.

```
extern crate serde;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate serde_json;

fn main() {
    let _: X = serde_json::from_str(r#"{ "ok": true }"#).expect("with string");
    let _: X = serde_json::from_str("").expect("empty string");
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct X {
    ok: Option<bool>,
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1204fced2db80897cd5eab58aeabb946)

This is the struct I would like to deserialize into. I've tried adding `#[serde(skip_serializing_if = "some_func")]` to the field, but it doesn't change anything.

The error is

```
Error("EOF while parsing a value", line: 1, column: 0)
```

Is there a way to handle this properly, or do I always have to check the status code if it's 2xx before attempting to deserialize the response?

Comment: Can you provide your full attempt with `#[serde(skip_serializing_if...)]`, including `some_func`?

Comment: I've only attempted it with a simple func that just returned `true˙ to see if it works. Since it didn't (got the same error) I didn't really bother with it anymore.

Comment: Oh! Well, for one, you probably meant to use `#[serde(skip_deserializing)]`, not `#[serde(skip_serializing)]`. The latter only works when encoding the value. :)

Comment: Moreover, consider making a full [MCVE], by including a small `main` function deserializing an example of a response reproducing the issue. This makes the question much easier to address and much easier for us to help.

Comment: Ahh, right, I've totally missed that. :) I thought I can't use external crates on play, my bad, I'll edit my post.

Comment: If the API happens to return a HTTP 5xx with no content you want to treat that as success?

Comment: @Shepmaster That's a good point. I'm in control of the API so I know what responses it can return. Anyway, I just thought there's a way to return `Default` if the json is simply null/empty.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is that the empty string is not valid JSON according to most parsers including the one built into ES6 and apparently Serde. There are three possible solutions that I see to this problem.

- Return an empty dict from the endpoint
- Do not blindly attempt deserialization of the empty string checking first for the content length of the response body.
- Implement a custom `Deserialize` method

Comment: *the one built into ES6* — what does that mean? How does a specification have something "built-in"? Do you mean that some specific implementation of ES6 has this behavior (if so, which) or do you mean that the ES6 specification mandates this behavior?

Comment: I am referring to the parser built into my browser. I did manage to find the spec [as defined by ECMA](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf). It seems a bit ambiguous about whether zero tokens is valid, they neglected to say "one or more tokens". "A  JSON  text  is  a  sequence  of tokens  formed  from  Unicode  code  points  that  conforms  to  the  JSON  value  grammar" The spec does not mention if there can be zero tokens or not but the implementation indicates that there cannot be zero.

Comment: *I am referring to the parser built into my browser.* — in that case, your answer would be better suited to say "the one built into $mybrowser (version $browser_version)".